# NSIS: Set current user directory as default installation directory in nsis

Tags: nsis

what predefined variable to use to set the current user directory as default installtion directory in the script?

$INSTDIR path as "C:\Users{CURRENT_USER_ID}\Tools",
where {CURRENT_USER_ID} is the unique logged in domain ID of the user.(for e.g. ed00345)

```
; The default installation directory
InstallDir C:\Users\{Current_USER_ID}\Tools

; Set output path to the installation directory.
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> $PROFILE
>
> The user's profile directory. A typical path is C:\Documents and Settings\Foo.
>
> This constant is available on Windows 2000 and above.

```
InstallDir "$Profile\Tools"
```

but you should not really install programs there, please use `$LocalAppData\Programs` instead.